# What is the purpose of an ER model?

Tags: sql

Why is an ER model important when creating a database?

I have made ER models before but want to know the importance

Answer (score 1):

ER diagram, is essential for modeling the data stored in a database. It is the basic design upon which a database is built. ER diagrams specify what data we will store: the entities and their attributes. They also show how entities relate to other entities. It also represents the data in a graphical manner. This makes it easier for business folks to understand. [You can refer to this article for more understanding.](https://vertabelo.com/blog/why-need-an-er-diagram/#:%7E:text=An%20entity-relationship%20diagram%2C%20or,entities%20relate%20to%20other%20entities.)

Answer (score 0):

ER Diagram in DBMS is widely used to describe the conceptual design of databases. It helps both users and database developers to preview the structure of the database before implementing the database.